# How to show the contents of one folder in Assets?

Tags: assets

I'm totally confused about Assets. I'm just trying to show the contents of a folder in a template. Here's my folder structure (dashes indicate subfolders):

```
Docs
-staff
--board
-public
Images
Logos
```

How would I display the contents of, say, the "public" folder? For some reason I'm not getting it.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

You're after the [exp:assets:files](http://docs.pixelandtonic.com/assets/templating/module/files.html) template tag:

```
{exp:assets:files folder="{filedir_1}public"}
            <li>File name: {filename}</li>
{/exp:assets:files}
```

Change {filedir_1} to whatever is appropriate for your Assets field.

To find what your filedir id is, go to **Content → Files → File Upload Preferences** and hover your mouse cursor over the appropriate "**Edit**" icon for the directory.

Within your browsers status bar, you will see "id=X". Use this number within {filedir_X}, for example in my screenshot mine is {filedir_1}.

[image: Find File Directory ID]

**Note:** It's not clear in your answer, but if your "Server Path to Upload Directory" is set to something like /home/me/www/assets/docs" and you've created the "public" directory within Assets. Then your correct folder path to 'public' is: `folder="{filedir_1}public"`

Comment: Oh, so I don't have to wrap it in the exp:assets:folder tag?

Comment: Also, how would I determine the correct filedir?

Comment: @MikeMella No, this works without the folder tag. And I've updated my answer on how to find your filedir ID.

Comment: Hmm, still no-go. I can make it work using folder_id=, but not folder=. My path is /home/me/public_html/images/uploads/docs/ and the other dirs are made in Assets. Status bar shows me that it's filedir_1. Even this shows nothing (this folder does contain files):  {exp:assets:files folder="{filedir_1}"}.

Comment: Hmm, this is definitely working for me using Assets 2.2.2/EE 2.7.3. Take a look at my working example [screenshot](https://www.mpasqualone.com/files/2014/Assets_list_folder.png) and double check everything on your end.

Comment: Nope, it's definitely not working for me. Same versions. Thanks for helping with this, but maybe I'll speak with P&T directly to get this resolved. Something's wonky.